# LoRaWAN rfm95w API/connection

Tags: arduino, lora, lorawan

I'm working on a lorawan protocol with a RFM95W module and an Arduino Uno. I have some issues with the connection to my MultiTech gateway.

I'd like to use LMIC API but I didn't know how I can get the APPEUI, the DEVEUI, and the APPKEY if I tried a connection by OTAA and I have the same problem for the NWKSKEY, the APPSKEY, and the DEVADDR when I'm trying a TNB connection. And how can I know if my gateway supports these connections types?

If someone can explain to me where I can find this information, it will be nice.

Many thanks in anticipation of your response.

A.F.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about this [Multitech](http://www.multitech.com/brands/multiconnect-conduit), than yes it supports both OTA and ABP join methods. however you'll need to set the **same**  APPEUI and APPKEY for both your end device and [gateway](http://www.multitech.net/developer/software/lora/conduit-aep-lora-communication/aep-lora-use-third-party-devices/) .  Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you choose the AppEUI/AppKey? You buy it from some international group like IEEE or you choose it randomly, crossing finger nobody else chose the same pair?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your gateway has a Network Server embedded, you probably need to configure it to use an existing external (or setup your own) network server.

In case you don't want to mess (a lot) with setting this up, I encourage you to check https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/ which is basically a free & open-source worldwide LoRaWan network